# Add new definitions to the model

Tags: pimcore

I'm trying to add some fields (e.g; photo) to an existing Object_Client class.

When i wrote a method to save photo:

```
public function setPhoto ($photo) {
    $this->photo = $photo;
    return $this;
}
```

I found that the class does not save it, I recognize this

When I var_dump it

```
  public 'fieldDefinitions' => 
array (size=11)
  'email' => 
    object(Object_Class_Data_UniqueInput)[126]
      public 'fieldtype' => string 'uniqueInput' (length=11)
      public 'regex' => string '^([a-zA-Z0-9_-])+([.]?[a-zA-Z0-9_-]{1,})*@([a-zA-Z0-9-_.]{1,}[.])+[a-zA-Z]{2,4}$' (length=80)
      public 'width' => string '' (length=0)
      public 'queryColumnType' => string 'varchar' (length=7)
      public 'columnType' => string 'varchar' (length=7)
      public 'columnLength' => int 255
      public 'phpdocType' => string 'string' (length=6)
      public 'name' => string 'email' (length=5)
      public 'title' => string 'E-mail' (length=6)
      public 'tooltip' => string '' (length=0)
      public 'mandatory' => boolean true
      public 'noteditable' => boolean false
      public 'index' => boolean false
      public 'locked' => boolean false
      public 'style' => string '' (length=0)
      public 'permissions' => null
      public 'datatype' => string 'data' (length=4)
      public 'relationType' => boolean false
      public 'invisible' => boolean false
      public 'visibleGridView' => boolean false
      public 'visibleSearch' => boolean false
  'password' => 
    object(Object_Class_Data_Password)[127]
      public 'fieldtype' => string 'password' (length=8)
      public 'width' => string '' (length=0)
      public 'queryColumnType' => string 'varchar(32)' (length=11)
      public 'columnType' => string 'varchar(32)' (length=11)
      public 'phpdocType' => string 'string' (length=6)
      public 'name' => string 'password' (length=8)
      public 'title' => string 'Mot de passe' (length=12)
      public 'tooltip' => string '' (length=0)
      public 'mandatory' => boolean false
      public 'noteditable' => boolean false
      public 'index' => boolean false
      public 'locked' => boolean false
      public 'style' => string '' (length=0)
      public 'permissions' => null
      public 'datatype' => string 'data' (length=4)
      public 'relationType' => boolean false
      public 'invisible' => boolean false
      public 'visibleGridView' => boolean false
      public 'visibleSearch' => boolean false
  'civilite' => 
    object(Object_Class_Data_Select)[129]
      public 'fieldtype' => string 'select' (length=6)
      public 'options' => 
        array (size=3)
          ...
```

Do I need to make photo available in some way, or create a definition for it ??

Comment: The question that I want to ask is : how to define fields for an object already created ??

Comment: Just to clarify your question - the goal is to change the structure of an object without using the GUI (which does all the magic w/ the code generation); Correct? I am curious - What is your use-case?

Answer (score 0):

Usually we use GUI to edit DataObject structure.

If you really need to edit configuration file, you can do it but remember to create new classes in the database from your configuration files.

```
./bin/console pimcore:deployment:classes-rebuild --create-classes
```

https://pimcore.com/docs/platform/Pimcore/Deployment/Deployment_Tools/